# Cannot log in to the admin, no error message

Tags: wp-admin, errors

After a WP autoupdate, I cannot log in to the admin.

I have not changed my site URL. I have tried renaming my theme so WP uses the default theme. I've tried renaming the plugins folder so WP doesn't load any plugins. I've tried a clean install (except for wp-config and wp-content). No luck.

When I try to log in, at http://submergemag.com/wp-login.php, the page refreshes without showing an error message and changes the URL to http://submergemag.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsubmergemag.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1. If I use an incorrect password, the error message appears as designed and tells me so.

I turned on registration through phpMyAdmin and was not able to register either. It says "ERROR: Couldn’t register you… please contact the webmaster!". I think this may be related. http://submergemag.com/wp-login.php?action=register

Has anyone else ran into this issue? How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable the plugins via the database running this query in your MySQL:

```
 UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

Also, try to enable error debugging in your wp-config.php file adding this line:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Also, could you paste a copy of your .htaccess file?